# From date and to date validation?

Tags: asp.net

in my web application, i write the compare validater for comparing the two dates [From and to date], but it is showing error. My Compare validator is like this.

```
 <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" Text="*" Display="None" ValidationGroup ="a" ControlToValidate="txtTo" ValueToCompare="txtFrom" Operator="GreaterThan"   Type ="Date" 
                    ErrorMessage="Date Should Greater Than From Date"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use "ControlToCompare" property instead of "ValueToCompare" property.

Like Following

```
 <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" Text="*" Display="None" ValidationGroup ="a" ControlToValidate="txtTo" ControlToCompare="txtFrom" Operator="GreaterThan"   Type ="Date" 
                ErrorMessage="Date Should Greater Than From Date"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

Comment: Hi Reshma thank you yaar, it is working fine, really i forget the property controltocompare. @suryasasidhar13@gmail.com

Comment: now it is not validating correctly for example when i select '1/1/2012' and to date '25/1/2012' it is giving message Date should greater than form date @reshma

Comment: @suryasasidhar ur should try This ControlToCompare="txtTo" and ControlToValidate="txtFrom"